# Button click won't showing the conditional card in the content material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-bardeen-ojm27?file=/src/App.js).

My goal is: when I click on Login button, content will show the Login card and when I click on Register button content will show the Register card.

As for my primary test, I used the following code:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const Login=()=>{
  return(
    <form>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" value="username"/>
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="password" value="password"/>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
 const Register=()=>{

  return(
    <form>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" value="name"/>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" value="username"/>
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="password" value="password"/>
      <button>Register</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const [click,setClick]=useState(false)
  const handleClick=()=>{
    setClick(true)
  } 
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>
      {click?<Login/>:<Register/>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And it works. In this way I tried to render functionalities in different components. It seems like not working. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is working and what is not? Please expand on the "functionalities" you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following corrections will help you:-
You need to make `App` component responsible for maintaining click state and then pass only handler (`setClick`) to `AppBar` and only state (`click`) to `Content`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Login from "./Login";
import Register from "./Register";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
}));

function Appbar({ handleClick }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            ReactApp
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit" onClick={()=>handleClick(true)}>
            Login
          </Button>
          <Button color="inherit" onClick={()=>handleClick(false)}>
            Register
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
function Content({ click }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container style={{ padding: 80 }} item>
        <Grid xs={false} sm={4} />
        <Grid xs={12} sm={8} />
        {click ? (
          <Login onClick={handleClick} />
        ) : (
          <Register onClick={handleClick} />
        )}
        <Grid />
        <Grid xs={false} sm={2} />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(true);
  const handleClick = (value) => {
    setClick(value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Appbar handleClick={handleClick} />
      <Content click={click} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it's working but the problem is when click on register again the card changes to Login card. my future goal is write hooks about Login and registration and when registration is done, user will click on Login button in Appbar and it will be directed to Login card. but here iteration is going. how can it be solved to pause the iteration

Comment: I have edited my answer. I was mistakenly flipping the boolean. Now I am not. Please check it.

Comment: now it's working....though i put some extra code  <Button
            color="inherit"
            onClick={e => {
              e.preventDefault();
              handleClick(true);
            }}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
          <Button
            color="inherit"
            onClick={e => {
              e.preventDefault();
              handleClick(false);
            }}
          >.....any way your code works fine and thanx for you help....appreciate it